# cvNot lead to exception in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, opencv

Why an exception happen when I use cvNot? it's Objective c Code

```
cv::Mat gray= //Get source image, Gray Image
cv::Mat bw=gray>128;
cv::Mat des;
cvNot(&bw,&des); // Exception happen here !
```

Comment: We're not psychic. What exception? What was the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cvNot is from the dreaded c-api, avoid that like hell !

stick with c++, cv::Mat and such, *please* !

use either :

```
bitwise_not(src,dst);
```

or :

```
des = ~src;
```

Comment: What about CvOr so? and CvAnd?

Comment: same story, avoid them !! bitwise_or, bitwise_and, etc.

Answer (score 0):

With your sample (replacing cvNot(&sr.&des) by cvNot(&sr, &des)) , you've got an *Unknown array type in function cvarrToMat*

If you use the C++ method

```
bitwise_not(sr, des);
```

That works.